# Opera mini trouble with form with more than 9 radio buttons

Tags: iphone, html, radio-button, opera, opera-mini

I am using opera mini on iphone to open a page where there are more than 9 options in a form and each option has a radio button. Problem I am currently facing is that I cannot select any option beyond the 9th one. Any suggestions?

```
<form>
<input id="min1" type="radio" name="operator1" value="min1"/></br>
<input id="min2" type="radio" name="operator1" value="min2"/></br>
<input id="min3" type="radio" name="operator1" value="min3"/></br>
<input id="min4" type="radio" name="operator1" value="min4"/></br>
<input id="min5" type="radio" name="operator1" value="min5"/></br>
<input id="min6" type="radio" name="operator1" value="min6"/></br>
<input id="min7" type="radio" name="operator1" value="min7"/></br>
<input id="min8" type="radio" name="operator1" value="min8"/></br>
<input id="min9" type="radio" name="operator1" value="min9"/></br>
<input id="min10" type="radio" name="operator1" value="min10"/></br>

cannot select any option beyond this.

<input id="min11" type="radio" name="operator1" value="min11"/></br>
<input id="min12" type="radio" name="operator1" value="min12"/></br>
<input id="min13" type="radio" name="operator1" value="min13"/></br>
<input id="min14" type="radio" name="operator1" value="min14"/></br>
<input id="min15" type="radio" name="operator1" value="min15"/></br>
<input id="min16" type="radio" name="operator1" value="min16"/></br>
<input id="min17" type="radio" name="operator1" value="min17"/></br>
<input id="min18" type="radio" name="operator1" value="min18"/></br>
</form>
```

Comment: Note: `id` must be unique. Either remove all of those `id`s or make them unique. `name` should still be the same across all of them. Also, the `value` should all be different, right? What's the point if they're all the same?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. However making the ids and value unique does not change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Are you dynamically generating the list?

I was able to reproduce the issue with jsfiddle, which dynamically creates the output: http://jsfiddle.net/rHpQ7/3/embedded/result/

But I was not able to reproduce the issue with a static page: http://framba.ch/test.html

Opera Mini has bad support for dynamic content, this has always been an issue. Best you can do is give the `<body>` a height ahead of time, like `style="height:800px"` if you think you'll need that much. Sorry this turned out to be a non-answer, but opera mini is not meant to handle dynamic content.

Comment: I got the error with the static page on iphone operamini. I ended up using select tag instead.

Thanks for the help though.